# Insertar datos en un txt - Python

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente función para agregar datos a un archivo TXT

```
def agregarUser():
    entrada = open('archivos/agenda.txt','w')
    cedula = 0
    name = input('')
    cedula = int(input(''))
    entrada.write(name+"\n"+str(cedula)+"\n")
    entrada.close()
```

No se si lo estoy formulando de la manera correcta, ya que al ingresar el primer USER bien, pero si quiero agregar otro se sobrescribe el primer dato

Answer (score 2):

Eso te está sucediendo por el modo que usas al abrir el archivo, especificas 'w', esto básicamente sobre escribe, para que solo agregue y no sobre escriba entonces usa 'a'

```
entrada = open('archivos/agenda.txt','a')
```